# Are there hidden armor spawns as in previous games?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA V I've only been able to find health kits spawning in the world, are there places where armor spawns as in [the previous games](http://faqsmedia.ign.com/faqs/image/article/875/875341/map_armora.jpg)?

Comment: I'm sure there are. I remember picking up one, but forgot where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are armor placed around the map.
Here are the locations (I will update the answer with a map as soon as I can find a nice picture): Elysian Island, Dutch London Street of Rancho, El Burro heights, Del Perro in Maze Bank, Little Seoul, West Vinewood, Hawick, Chumash, Great Chaparral, Fort Zancudo, Mount Josiah, Grapeseed, Land Act Dam, Palmer-Taylor Power Station, Vinewood Hills, Redwood Lights Track, Richman Glen gas station, Tongva Hills, Galilee, Paleto Forest, Sandy Shores, Vinewood Posile Department, Los Santos Police Department, Vespucci Police Department, Rancho Police Station, Los Santos International Airport and Vespucci Pier Walkway.

**UPDATE**: Here is a nice [interactive map](http://www.gta-5-map.com/) that shows (among other things) every single body armor in the game

[Source](http://segmentnext.com/2013/09/20/gta-5-weapons-and-armor-tips-locations-and-customization-guide/)

Comment: The ones inside the police stations are the easiest to find. Thanks. A map would be great though!